# Highlight Rows based on Active Cell But background color shouldn't remove

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using below code which is working perfectly but one one thing is wrong that I have been trying to remove from so long but couldn't find a way to fix the problem.

Issue is that when I run the code and move the cursor to any cell it removes the all background color of active sheet. I don't want to remove the background colors.

Finding a solution moving an cursor on any cell just highlight the row with selected color if I moved to other cell upper or lower, Background color should not be removed.

```
   function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, maxRows - 1, maxColumns).setBackground(null);
  if (range.getRow() > 1) {
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, maxColumns).setBackground("#c9daf8");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation - Updated based on OPs comments:

- OP wants to set the background color of the **white** cells `#ffffff`
  with a blue color `#c9daf8`.
- **But** if the row contains other colors rather than **white** he wants to **keep** these background colors and **only change** the background color of the **white** cells.
- One way to achieve that, is to get the current background colors and use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to replace only the white colors `#ffffff` with `#c9daf8`:

`const bc = range_row.getBackgrounds().flat().map(c=>c=='#ffffff'?'#c9daf8':c);`

---

### Solution:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  if (range.getRow() > 1) {
    const range_row = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, maxColumns);
    const bc = range_row.getBackgrounds().flat().map(c=>c=='#ffffff'?'#c9daf8':c);
    range_row.setBackgrounds([bc]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Marios i have already tried this but after removing this line the highlighted row color is not removed it remains on sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rPInQAoDBVPWUd0I2L9y9LHOL7VTTsoiygd9jj62zd4/edit?usp=sharing please have a look.

Comment: This is what you wanted right ? `if I moved to other cell upper or lower, Background color should not be removed.` @Shazir the script above `does not` remove the background color if you click on a cell.

Comment: @Shazir Please explain clearly what you want. You want to remove the background color of the other cells or not? Based on your question, I understand that you **don't** want to remove it. On the other hand, if you want to remove it, then your code works just fine. Please provide details so we can help you.

Comment: I have added color to the column A when i move the cursor to any cell the color of the cell will be removed.

Comment: Issue is if Col A,B,C and D have Red color if i move the cursor to the Row 6 then red color will be removed and script color will be pasted on the entire row even after moving the cursor script color not removed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: looking forward to you response?

Comment: @Shazir could you please post a new question if you want more changes so future readers can benefit from those as well? thanks :)